# Xamarin.iOS change local notification title automatically everyday

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications

I'm working on a project where I need to set a different title for local notification in a specific day (lets say for Monday) with the same trigger time as the days before. How can I proceed with doing it ? I tried creating two different requests one with a repeating parameter and the other not, but then i got a duplicated notification for the "Monday" one.
Any solution to change the title for this case just only for one day and repeating ?

Comment: You would need to create one notification for each day, with a repeat period of weekly

Comment: @Paulw11 how can i repeat the notification weekly ? I believe this code is for a daily repeat 
`var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(dateComponents, true);`

Comment: You would specify the `weekday` component of your `DateComponents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create different `UNNotificationRequest` with `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and `UNMutableNotificationContent` to implement this.Then you will get notification with different titles in a week.

For example, create day1 like this:

```
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger trigger1 = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(new NSDateComponents() { Weekday = 1, Hour = 8}, true);
UNMutableNotificationContent content1 = new UNMutableNotificationContent() { Title = "Day1", Body = "Day1", CategoryIdentifier = "Day1" };
UNNotificationRequest request1 = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier("d1", content1, trigger1);
```

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for